# Difference between R.scale() and sklearn.preprocessing.scale()

Tags: python, r, scale, scikit-learn

I am currently moving my data analysis from R to Python. When scaling a dataset in R i would use R.scale(), which in my understanding would do the following: (x-mean(x))/sd(x)

To replace that function I tried to use sklearn.preprocessing.scale(). From my understanding of the description it does the same thing. Nonetheless I ran a little test-file and found out, that both of these methods have different return-values. Obviously the standard deviations are not the same... Is someone able to explain why the standard deviations "deviate" from one another?

MWE:

```
# import packages
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
# Set up R namespaces
R = rpy2.robjects.r


np1 = numpy.array([[1.0,2.0],[3.0,1.0]])
print "Numpy-array:"
print np1

print "Scaled numpy array through R.scale()"
print R.scale(np1)
print "-------"
print "Scaled numpy array through preprocessing.scale()"
print preprocessing.scale(np1, axis = 0, with_mean = True, with_std = True)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(np1)
print "Mean of preprocessing.scale():"
print scaler.mean_
print "Std of preprocessing.scale():"
print scaler.std_
```

Output:
[image: Output generated by the MWE]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to have to do with how standard deviation is calculated.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 1]])
>>> np.std(a, axis=0)
array([ 1. ,  0.5])
>>> np.std(a, axis=0, ddof=1)
array([ 1.41421356,  0.70710678])
```

From `numpy.std` [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html),

> ddof : int, optional
>
> Means Delta Degrees of Freedom. The divisor used in calculations is N - ddof, where N represents the number of elements. By default ddof is zero.

Apparently, `R.scale()` uses `ddof=1`, but `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()` uses `ddof=0`.

EDIT: (To explain how to use alternate ddof)

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to calculate std with alternate ddof, without accessing the variables of the StandardScaler() object itself.

```
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(data)
# Now, sc.mean_ and sc.std_ are the mean and standard deviation of the data
# Replace the sc.std_ value using std calculated using numpy
sc.std_ = numpy.std(data, axis=0, ddof=1)
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your help! Is there an easy way to pass ddof=1 to the sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler() or do I have to write my own scale-function? Actually I don't want to overuse the R-environment, as it seems to be slower than the sklearn version... So a solution in python would be my goal.

Comment: Not possible in the `StandardScaler` as it is. The fact that you are using sklearn indicates to me that you are more out for machine learning than classical statistics? If this is the case I'd be curious to know about a case where this difference in degrees of freedom actually makes a difference.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do this, without accessing the variables of the `StandardScaler()` class. If `sc = StandardScaler()`, then `sc.mean_` and `sc.std_` are the mean and standard deviation, whose values are obtained by `sc.fit(data)`. Instead of running `sc.fit(data)` or after running the same, you could use numpy to calculate the mean and/or std, which would allow you to calculate std with ddof=1. 'sc.std_=np.std(data, axis=0, ddof=1)'.

Comment: @eickenberg: As you correctly stated I am more interested in the basic usage of machine learning. The only reason why I am asking this is because I noticed the difference in the standard deviation and was curious what it would do to my overall problem. As I am migrating my code from R to Python, I have some old calculations which are based on the ddof=1 calculation of the standard deviation. Thus, using a different sd would somehow render my solutions faulty. Nonetheless, this only matters for now... But still I didn't know about the many possibilities to calculate the sd!

Comment: `sc.std_ = np.std(X, axis=0, ddof=1)`  does not change the result from `sc.fit_transform(data)`  even though I have tried to replace the standard deviation with the degree of freedom adjusted one.  I would like to know if anyone has successfully changed the standardization result with `StandardScaler`.

Comment: @Sarah The scaler needs to be fitted via sc.fit(..), next sc.std_ is set, and finally sc.transform(...) can be called, so this should not work with sc.fit_transform(..).

Comment: sklearn has changed. The new syntax you need to use between sc.fit() and sc.transform() is: sc.scale_ = np.std(data, axis=0, ddof=1).to_list()

Answer (score 2):

The current answers are good, but sklearn has changed a bit meanwhile. The new syntax that makes sklearn behave exactly like R.scale() now is:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(data)
sc.scale_ = np.std(data, axis=0, ddof=1).to_list()
sc.transform(data)
```

Feature request:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/23758

Answer (score 0):

`R.scale` documentation says:

> The root-mean-square for a (possibly centered) column is defined as sqrt(sum(x^2)/(n-1)), where x is a vector of the non-missing values and n is the number of non-missing values. In the case center = TRUE, this is the same as the standard deviation, but in general it is not. (To scale by the standard deviations without centering, use scale(x, center = FALSE, scale = apply(x, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)).)

However, `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScale` always scale with standard deviation.

In my case, I want to replicate R.scale in Python without centered,I followed @Sid advice in a slightly different way:

```
import numpy as np

def get_scale_1d(v):
    # I copy this function from R source code haha
    v = v[~np.isnan(v)]
    std = np.sqrt(
        np.sum(v ** 2) / np.max([1, len(v) - 1])
    )
    return std

sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(data)
sc.std_ = np.apply_along_axis(func1d=get_scale_1d, axis=0, arr=x)
sc.transform(data)
```